# Can i use "classic" ml models with keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I wonder if i can use keras framework with "classic" models like (xg-boost / random forest / linear-logistic) regression instead of neural network?

I saw there is a class named:

```
tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier
```

But not sure how i can use it with keras dataset

Can u assist?